# What's the current through the 2Ω resistance? The question requires me to find the answer by using Thevenin's theorem

Tags: thevenin

This is the circuit. I have found Thevenin equivalent resistance to be 5 ohm. Is that correct?
I am not able to find the Thevenin equivalent voltage across the load resistance.

[image]

These are the steps that I took to get the Thevenin equivalent resistance:

1. I removed the load resistance
2. I calculated the remaining resistances: [(4+6)||(6+4)] = 5 ohm

Comment: It all depends where you specify it to be. If it's across the connections of RL with RL removed then sorry, 5 ohms isn't correct.

Comment: How did you get 5Ω? Also, why you are not able to find the Vth voltage. Did you remove the 2Ω resistor from a circuit? After that, you should see two voltage dividers.

Comment: @G36 I did remove the 2ohm resistor. But I didn't get you. Please help.

Comment: @Andyaka how to do it properly?

Comment: It doesn't work like that - you should show your working to get 5 ohm. Embed that into your question then we'll be able to spot your error and point it out to you. You also need to confirm where the Thevenin impedance is measured/calculated. These things are important to state in your question. Nobody is going to guess them for you.

Comment: did as you said @Andyaka. Actually I've just started solving these type of questions, sorry for the incomplete question. Also I need to find the resistance (and not impedance) across the 2ohm resistor.

Comment: Show us how you would redraw the circuit to remove the load and the source. Remember that if you combine resistors in series the node between them effectively disappears from your circuit.

Comment: You have to short the voltage source as well for thevenin resistance and you'll get (4||6 +4||6)=4.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a hint, consider that your circuit behaves exactly the same as this one:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK7T2y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now you should be able to see how you can apply Thevenin's theorem (two times) to simplify this circuit to the point where you'll be able to find the current through R5 by inspection.